# How do I enable connections to a MySQL database from a Virtual PC using SQL Developer

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, networking

I've got a MySQL Database on my local machine (Windows 7).

My local machine hosts 2 VMWare virtual machines. One running windows xp and the other running Ubuntu.

I want to access the MySQL database on my local machine using SQLDeveloper on the windows XP virtual machine.

The Ubuntu machine is able to access the database from within a java app using url jdbc:mysql://Peter-PC:3306/accessodev and a user/pass

When I attempt to connect from the windows XP box use SQLDeveloper I get a message saying: Communications link failure. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Both the Ubuntu and Windows XP machines fail to connect using telnet Peter-PC 3306. Both machines successfully resolve Peter-PC to the correct IP address.

The Win 7 Machine can telnet to itself using telnet Peter-PC 3306. The windows firewall is turned off on this machine.

Can anyone give me any tips on how I can get connectivity to the MySQL database from the WinXP machine using SQLDeveloper?

Edit: I'm using the driver from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably stating the obvious here but have you granted permission to the virtual machines to connect to the MySQL server (`grant all permissions on database.* to 'winxp'@'a.b.c.d' identified by 'passwordhere'; flush privileges;`)? And on the XP machine, have you allowed the SQLDevloper app through the firewall? Might be worth running up Wireshark on the host machine to see exactly what's coming through to the host machine too

Comment: You have to grant permissions to machines? I thought you just gave permissions to users? I sorta figure the permissions must be ok or the Ubuntu machine wouldn't be able to connect from within a java app. The user has permission to hosts matching %. If I do need to set stuff elsewhere, where/how do I set it? VirtXP box firewall is turned off as well.

Comment: You can set it via a GRANT command on the MySQL server. You would use something like "`grant all permissions on accessodev.* to 'user'@'a.b.c.d' indentified by 'password'; flush privileges;`" where a.b.c.d is the IP address that the Windows XP virtual machine is identifying itself as to the MySQL server. The easiest way I've found to get the IP address is to try to connect to the server via the command line of the XP machine, let it fail and then read off the address from the error message